# An error equivalent for process.text?

Tags: groovy

[You can get the entire output stream](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management) by using .text:

```
def process = "ls -l".execute()
println "Found text ${process.text}"
```

Is there a concise equivalent to get the error stream?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `waitForProcessOutput` which takes two Appendables ([docs here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#waitForProcessOutput%28java.lang.Appendable,%20java.lang.Appendable%29))

```
def process = "ls -l".execute()
def (output, error) = new StringWriter().with { o -> // For the output
  new StringWriter().with { e ->                     // For the error stream
    process.waitForProcessOutput( o, e )
    [ o, e ]*.toString()                             // Return them both
  }
}
// And print them out...
println "OUT: $output"
println "ERR: $error"
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer because it's the most concise so far. I wonder why there isn't a `process.error`.

Comment: mainly because using the .text member is dangerous.  If the text output to either the output or error streams exceeds the buffersize, then your process will halt until some of the stream is read.  It's actually a good idea when you don't know how long the output will be (which is usually the case for errors) to use a separate thread to capture the stream.

Comment: +1 for @BillJames comment.  As an aside, this is what [`waitForProcessOutput` does](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ProcessGroovyMethods.java#L206) (creates two threads to listen for output)

Comment: What is the splat operator here? I haven't seen this before. Is it a spread operator to get a string value and assign each to the respective variables that were declared?

Comment: Yup  it calls toString on both the string writers, returns that as a list of two strings and they get signed to the two variables via multiple assignment http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_multiple_assignment

Comment: If you're writing Groovy for Jenkins, the spread operator is not supported. I received the error `spread not yet supported for CPS transformation` but was able to replace it with `[o, e].collect { it.toString() }`.

Answer (score 4):

Based on tim_yates answer, I tried it on Jenkins and found this issue with multiple assignment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45575

So this works and it is also concise:

```
def process = "ls -l".execute()
def output = new StringWriter(), error = new StringWriter()
process.waitForProcessOutput(output, error)
println "exit value=${process.exitValue()}"
println "OUT: $output"
println "ERR: $error"
```

Answer (score 0):

By `.redirectErrorStream(true)` you tell process **to merge error and output streams**:

```
def process = new ProcessBuilder()
    .redirectErrorStream(true)
    .command(["ls", "-l"])
    .start()
println "exit value=${process.waitFor()}"
println "OUT: ${process.text}"
```

Drawback - you need to split command line onto a separate components `["ls", "-l"]` instead of a simple string `"ls -l"`.