# How do I run a PowerShell command from groovy the same way as "cmd /c <command>".execute()?

Tags: windows, powershell, groovy

In Groovy I can run the Windows cmd shell directly and read the result like this:

```
def proc = "cmd /c dir".execute()
proc.wait()
println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}"
```

However, if I try this with PowerShell it blocks and won't return:

```
def proc = "powershell dir".execute()
```

I have tried

```
def proc = "powershell -NonInteractive dir".execute()
```

etc. - but they all block and I have to kill the Groovy script.

What's the equivalent of the `/c` switch for cmd that you use with PowerShell to get the result to return to the script.

Comment: Have you tried consuming the streams? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10688731/6509

Comment: nope that doesnt seem to work either - i did this code:   def process = "powershell ls".execute()
def (output, error) = new StringWriter().with { o -> // For the output
  new StringWriter().with { e ->                     // For the error stream
    process.waitForProcessOutput( o, e )
    [ o, e ]*.toString()                             // Return them both
  }
}
// And print them out...
println "OUT: $output"
println "ERR: $error"   and it hangs in groovy script as my other example does

Answer (score 4):

You can use the List form:

```
['powershell', '-command', 'dir'].execute()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the -command parameter:

`powershell -command "dir"`

Comment: tried def proc = 'powershell -command  "dir"'.execute()  and it hangs in the script

Answer (score 3):

I used a Groovy class to execute a PowerShell script. This is a little more elaborate than just executing a command, but I thought it might be helpful.

```
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
@Log4j
class PowerShellUtil {

    def exec(debug, command, args){

        def powerShellCommand = ".\\${command} ${args}"
        def shellCommand = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile  -Command \"${powerShellCommand}\""

        if (debug) log.debug powerShellCommand

        def process = shellCommand.execute()
        def out = new StringBuffer()
        def err = new StringBuffer()
        process.consumeProcessOutput(out, err)
        process.waitFor()
        if(out.size() > 0 && debug) log.debug out
        if(err.size() > 0) log.error err
    }
}
```

Then I can execute the script with:

```
PowerShellUtil psUtil = new PowerShellUtil()
psUtil.exec(true, 'script.ps1','script-args')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
powershell -command dir
```

Answer (score 0):

For a **simple command** like list directory:

```
powershell -command ls
```

For making a **PowerShell script** run in cmd you should use an **encoded command** like:

```
$script = {Get-EventLog -LogName System -Newest 10 | where { $_.Index -ge 5071811 } | sort Index}
```

then:

```
 [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes( $script))
RwBlAHQALQBFAHYAZQBuAHQATABvAGcAIAAtAEwAbwBnAE4AYQBtAGUAIABTAHkAcwB0AGUAbQAgAC0ATgBlAHcAZQBzAHQAIAAxADAAIAB8ACAAdwBoAGU
AcgBlACAAewAgACQAXwAuAEkAbgBkAGUAeAAgAC0AZwBlACAANQAwADcAMQA4ADEAMQAgAH0AIAB8ACAAcwBvAHIAdAAgAEkAbg
```

My result:

```
C:\Users\soheil>powershell -encodedcommand RwBlAHQALQBFAHYAZQBuAHQATABvAGcAIAAtA
EwAbwBnAE4AYQBtAGUAIABTAHkAcwB0AGUAbQAgAC0ATgBlAHcAZQBzAHQAIAAxADAAIAB8ACAAdwBoA
GUAcgBlACAAewAgACQAXwAuAEkAbgBkAGUAeAAgAC0AZwBlACAANQAwADcAMQA4ADEAMQAgAH0AIAB8A
CAAcwBvAHIAdAAgAEkAbgBkAGUAeAA=


   Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------
 5071812 Mar 10 22:39  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Mul...
 5071813 Mar 10 22:40  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The App...
 5071814 Mar 10 22:45  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Mul...
 5071815 Mar 10 22:48  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Dia...
 5071816 Mar 10 22:55  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Mul...
 5071817 Mar 10 22:58  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Mul...
 5071818 Mar 10 22:59  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Goo...
 5071819 Mar 10 22:59  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Goo...
 5071820 Mar 10 23:14  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Mul...
 5071821 Mar 10 23:30  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Mul...
```

Comment: is encoding even necessary when executing it as a process?

Comment: Encodedcommand very usefull just one code and use to all shell ,all of hacker use this when access from any windows site because site just cmd not have powershell access...,when u send user pass from script just one gateway can monitore ur packet and get ur pass just my idea :)

Comment: didn't answer question - I tried def proc = 'powershell -command  "dir"'.execute()  and this hangs - if I use "cmd /c dir" the execute

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
    // powershell.groovy file
def executePowershellCommand(String command, boolean returnStdout = false) {
    def result
    def wrappedCommand = """
    @echo off
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('powershell -noProfile -executionPolicy bypass -command "& { ${command} }"') do (
        echo %%a
    )
    """
    result = bat script: wrappedCommand, returnStdout: returnStdout

    if (returnStdout) result = result.trim()

    return result
}

return this
```